# How do find broken document links in SharePoint libraries

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

We are trying to find all broken document links in a SharePoint document library.  These links are stored in libraries as .url files.  The file itself contains the link we want to test.  Using powershell, we submit the link to invoke-webrequest.  But we always get a 200 (page found) result, even for known broken links.  When we look at the response package, we see that SharePoint is returning the "Login page", which means we most likely do not have permission to access the link via invoke-webrequest.  We are connecting using
-WebLogin, not -Interactive.

```
    $text = Get-PnPFile -Url $Item.FileRef -AsString # get content of the .url file
    # parse file to get target link as $link_url
    $result = (invoke-webrequest $link_url - DisableKeepAlive -UseBasicParsing)
```

always returns

StatusCode :200 
StatusDescription:OK 
Content: ...

Always returns sign-in page.

Comment: To be clear, we are using Multi-Factor Authentication in our tenant

Answer (score 1):

How you tried running the script using the credentials option?

```
$text = Get-PnPFile -Url $Item.FileRef -AsString # get content of the .url file
# parse file to get target link as $link_url
$result = (invoke-webrequest $link_url - DisableKeepAlive -UseBasicParsing -UseDefaultCredentials)
```

Comment: Yes, -Credentials fails because we are using multi-factor authentication.  I also tried -Interactive but that doesn't seem to work either.  It seems to work with -DeviceLogin but I'm still getting 200's for the broken links.  Here is one hint: the header does return a parameter [SharePointError, 0] on the broken links but not the good links.  Could this be what I'm looking for?

Comment: Could you please add the part about MFA to your question?

Comment: We tried using -DeviceLogin and that seems to work fine.  When we hit the document links, we find that we still get the 200 response (because SharePoint is returning some page" but the headers are different.  For broken links, the header includes parameter [SharePointError,0].  Good links don't have this param.  Could this be sufficient to telling us which links are broken?

Comment: This was fixed by using -Interactive login which honors interactive login:Connect-PnPOnline  -Url $site_url -UseWebLogin

Comment: @DonaldKoscheka, Oh, you solved it? :) Could you add it as an answer and mark it as the actual solution?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me. Note that you will have to go to your browser to complete the login:

```
   Connect-PnPOnline  -Url $site_url -Interactive

   #Get all the items in this library
   $Items = (Get-PnPListItem -List $list_name  -PageSize 2500).FieldValues    

   foreach($Item in $Items)
   {
      if (($Item.FileRef).Contains(".url")){
        # this is a document link... do something with it.
      } 
      else{ 
        # this is a document, so do document things with it.,
      }
   } # for-each item in the library
```